# Prove that the position vector is perpendicular to the velocity vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

let $\vec{X}(t)$ be a differentiable curve, lies on a sphere of radius one, Prove that in any given point on the curve the position vector is perpendicular to the velocity vector.

in other words $$\vec{X}(t)\cdot\vec{X'}(t)=0$$

I think that this is an obvious question because the tangent to a sphere is always perpendicular to the radius. since the tangent is just $\vec{X'}(t)$ and the radius is $\vec{X}(t)$, we get the above equation.

but the author gave a hint, he says *Start from the condition $\vec{X^2}(t)=1$*, what does he mean by that? Does this mean that my solution is wrong?

Comment: The author means to prove it algebraically rather than assert based on geometric intuition. Being on the sphere of radius one means its norm is $1$, or in other words the dot product with itself is $1$, or $X\cdot X=1$. You can differentiate this equation with the product rule.

Comment: $$X(t)\cdot X(t)=1\implies 2X'(t)\cdot X=0\implies X'(t)\cdot X=0$$ Although i think that the geometric approach is fine in $3$D @runway44